# Objective c — Update parameter in block

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, objective-c-blocks

I was doing some tinkering with tree traversals (which I have solved in a much more straightforward way) but I have come across an issue in the following piece of Objective C logic:

```
- (NSString *)someWrapperFunction
{
    NSString *result = @"";

    NSString *(^appendBlock)(int, NSString **) = ^NSString *(int a, NSString **adder){
        if (a == 0)
        {
            // base case
            return @"";
        }

        NSLog(@"%d", a);

        *adder = [*adder stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%d-", a];

        NSLog(@"adder: %@", *adder);
        return [*adder stringByAppendingString:appendBlock(a-1, adder)];
    };

    appendBlock(5, &result);

    return result; 
}
```

Basically, I want to create a block of code that concatenates numbers into the given string (adder). The result should be: `"-5--4--3--2--1-"`.

I get a segmentation fault with the above code but with some other code that I wrote for the tree traversal, the adder string was essentially not getting updated. Any pointers to what I am doing wrong here? (Is it possible that the variable that is being updated by the inner block (inside recursion) is disallowed as it is already being occupied by the outer block OR is it just that `NSString` is non-mutable data type?)

In any case, I want to keep the design of the function the same; how would I solve this problem (using c/objective)?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Segmentation fault: possibly the last line that returns another recursion in the block.

Comment: Use the debugger and see which line exactly is causing the error. Then you'll have a starting point.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: I was just playing around with this code and I'm not 100% sure why it crashes but it occurs to me that there is no reason to be using an "out" parameter for `adder`. Why are you? Just use the return value.

Comment: I am not sure what "out" parameter you are referring to; maybe pointer to pointer? Anyway, I think its crashing because `appendBlock` is unknown. Can't recursively call the block like this.

Comment: given this block does not capture anything, you can convert it to plain C function and make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and experimenting I found a way to fix this.

1. There is no reason to be using a double-pointer for your `adder` parameter in the block. Just use a regular pointer and update your code accordingly.
2. The error is coming from the fact that inside of the block, `appendBlock` is `NULL` and you end up dereferencing the `NULL` pointer trying to call it.

Here's an updated version that works:

```
- (NSString *)someWrapperFunction
{
    NSString *result = @"";

    NSString *(^appendBlock)(int, NSString *);
    __block __weak NSString *(^weakBlock)(int, NSString *);
    weakBlock = appendBlock = ^NSString *(int a, NSString *adder){
        NSString *(^innerBlock)(int, NSString *) = weakBlock;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            // base case
            return @"";
        }

        NSLog(@"%d", a);

        adder = [adder stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%d-", a];

        NSLog(@"adder: %@", adder);

        // Split this update to make it easier to debug.
        NSString *update = innerBlock(a-1, adder);
        return [adder stringByAppendingString:update];
    };

    appendBlock(5, result);

    return result; 
}
```

Output: `"-5--4--3--2--1-"`

This update is rewritten for point #1 (which really has nothing to do with your original issue.

To solve point #2 this update creates the original `appendBlock` variable as well as a new `__block __weak weakBlock` reference to the same block. And then inside the block, a new (strong) block pointer is created to reference the weak block pointer. Without the use of the weak pointer, the code works but causes a warning.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I did figure out the problem (see discussion in your comment). Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: You never said how you fixed the crash. I didn't see that you fixed that part.

Comment: Oh I see. Ya I did fix it but given you had already spent some time, I wanted you to publish the answer (I should have specified that my bad).